# Any solutions to test SQL Agent Job immediately to ignore schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I want to test the execution correctness of my SQL Server Agent job immediately to ignore the schedule. Any ideas?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSMS, under the "SQL Server Agent" node, open the "Jobs" subnode and find your job, right click on it and select "Start Job" - that'll start and run the job right away.

[image]

Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, it is why I am confused. In SQL Server Management Studio it only has Start Job at Step... option, no Start Job option. Do you mean Start Job at Step... option?

Comment: Yes, that's the option to start a job.

Comment: If your job only has a single step (which I believe it has), the job will be started right away.

Comment: If your job has several steps, you can pick which one to start at - that's why it has this "Start Job at Step...." captoin.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that encapsulates all the aspects of your job and then use that in SQL Agent. You can then just call the procedure from the command line to test it eg. `exec dbo.MyProcedure @param1 = 'foo'`

Comment: Hi Dan, it is just a walk-around. My purpose is I want to test all settings in SQL Server Agent Job, besides schedule. Storeprocedure is only a part of all SQL Server Agent Job settings, I need to test other parts. Any comments or ideas? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the schedule to have it run five minutes in the future.
Then get off the server so it runs in **exactly** the environment you want to test.